# Yeoman error with webapp generator

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman

I installed Yeoman from npm and I get this error trying `yo webapp`. It seems to be related to the `grunt-contrib-compass` package but I can't tell what's going on, error `EPERM`?. The error lines are all at the end, I included the previous lines for context, maybe they provide some info. I don't understand this error, can anybody explain what it means? Is it a permissions issue? I tried with `sudo` but I've read is not recommended, and Yeoman tells me I should not run it with `sudo`.

```
671 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry package.json
672 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry README.md
673 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry Gruntfile.js
674 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry .jshintrc
675 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry AUTHORS
676 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry CHANGELOG
677 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry CONTRIBUTING.md
678 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry LICENSE-MIT
679 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry tasks/compass.js
680 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry tasks/lib/compass.js
681 silly lockFile bc64b16b-690-0-042454059002920985-package tar:///home/elclanrs/tmp/npm-18745/1374459607690-0.042454059002920985/package
682 silly lockFile bc64b16b-690-0-042454059002920985-package tar:///home/elclanrs/tmp/npm-18745/1374459607690-0.042454059002920985/package
683 silly lockFile e0825942-690-0-042454059002920985-tmp-tgz tar:///home/elclanrs/tmp/npm-18745/1374459607690-0.042454059002920985/tmp.tgz
684 silly lockFile e0825942-690-0-042454059002920985-tmp-tgz tar:///home/elclanrs/tmp/npm-18745/1374459607690-0.042454059002920985/tmp.tgz
685 verbose tar pack [ '/home/elclanrs/.npm/grunt-contrib-compass/0.2.0/package.tgz',
685 verbose tar pack   '/home/elclanrs/tmp/npm-18745/1374459607690-0.042454059002920985/package' ]
686 verbose tarball /home/elclanrs/.npm/grunt-contrib-compass/0.2.0/package.tgz
687 verbose folder /home/elclanrs/tmp/npm-18745/1374459607690-0.042454059002920985/package
688 silly lockFile bc64b16b-690-0-042454059002920985-package tar:///home/elclanrs/tmp/npm-18745/1374459607690-0.042454059002920985/package
689 verbose lock tar:///home/elclanrs/tmp/npm-18745/1374459607690-0.042454059002920985/package /home/elclanrs/.npm/bc64b16b-690-0-042454059002920985-package.lock
690 silly lockFile 12072454-ontrib-compass-0-2-0-package-tgz tar:///home/elclanrs/.npm/grunt-contrib-compass/0.2.0/package.tgz
691 verbose lock tar:///home/elclanrs/.npm/grunt-contrib-compass/0.2.0/package.tgz /home/elclanrs/.npm/12072454-ontrib-compass-0-2-0-package-tgz.lock
692 silly lockFile bc64b16b-690-0-042454059002920985-package tar:///home/elclanrs/tmp/npm-18745/1374459607690-0.042454059002920985/package
693 silly lockFile bc64b16b-690-0-042454059002920985-package tar:///home/elclanrs/tmp/npm-18745/1374459607690-0.042454059002920985/package
694 silly lockFile 12072454-ontrib-compass-0-2-0-package-tgz tar:///home/elclanrs/.npm/grunt-contrib-compass/0.2.0/package.tgz
695 silly lockFile 12072454-ontrib-compass-0-2-0-package-tgz tar:///home/elclanrs/.npm/grunt-contrib-compass/0.2.0/package.tgz
696 silly lockFile 07d965f9--grunt-contrib-compass-0-2-0-tgz https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-compass/-/grunt-contrib-compass-0.2.0.tgz
697 silly lockFile 07d965f9--grunt-contrib-compass-0-2-0-tgz https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-compass/-/grunt-contrib-compass-0.2.0.tgz
698 silly lockFile 91530c32-grunt-contrib-compass-0-2-0 grunt-contrib-compass@0.2.0
699 silly lockFile 91530c32-grunt-contrib-compass-0-2-0 grunt-contrib-compass@0.2.0
700 silly lockFile f2e16aab-grunt-contrib-compass-0-2-0 grunt-contrib-compass@~0.2.0
701 silly lockFile f2e16aab-grunt-contrib-compass-0-2-0 grunt-contrib-compass@~0.2.0
702 error Error: EPERM, chown '/home/elclanrs/.npm/grunt-contrib-compass/0.2.0/package.tgz'
702 error  { [Error: EPERM, chown '/home/elclanrs/.npm/grunt-contrib-compass/0.2.0/package.tgz']
702 error   errno: 50,
702 error   code: 'EPERM',
702 error   path: '/home/elclanrs/.npm/grunt-contrib-compass/0.2.0/package.tgz' }
703 error Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
704 error System Linux 3.9.10elclanrs
705 error command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
706 error cwd /home/elclanrs/Desktop/webapp
707 error node -v v0.10.13
708 error npm -v 1.3.2
709 error path /home/elclanrs/.npm/grunt-contrib-compass/0.2.0/package.tgz
710 error code EPERM
711 error errno 50
712 error stack Error: EPERM, chown '/home/elclanrs/.npm/grunt-contrib-compass/0.2.0/package.tgz'
713 verbose exit [ 50, true ]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is most likely a temporary npm error. Run `npm cache clean` and start over If this doesn't help, make sure you own the `$HOME/.npm` directory and change the owner in case you don't by running `chown -R $USER ~/.npm`.